# How to process and filter List items before passing to recyclerView on Android

Tags: android, loops, arraylist, logic, equals

In my application I want to show data retrieved from server.
 I want to filter data on recycler view based on **Won** attribute

**Specifically, By default show all items matching "won=false" unless "won=true" found, If at-least one item with "won=true" found, show only "won=true" items.**

How to check whether list datastructure contains atleast one item has value *true* for attribute *won*.

I write below codes to show all of data.
**My Adapter codes:**

```
public class AwardModelAdater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AwardModelAdater.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Award> model;
    private int modelImage;

    public AwardModelAdater(Context context, List<Award> model) {
        this.context = context;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public AwardModelAdater.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_award, parent, false);

        return new AwardModelAdater.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AwardModelAdater.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (model.get(position).getWon()) {
            modelImage = R.drawable.golden_globe_gold;
        } else {
            modelImage = R.drawable.golden_globe_silver;
        }

        if (model.get(position).getWon()) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(modelImage)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.row_awardImg);
        } else {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(modelImage)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.row_awardImg);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return model.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView row_awardImg;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            row_awardImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_awardImg);

        }
    }
}
```

**My activity code:**

```
SendData = new SerialDetailSendData();
SendData.setSeriesID(serialID);

InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
Call<SeriesAwardResponse> call = api.getSeriesAward(SendData);

call.enqueue(new Callback<SeriesAwardResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SeriesAwardResponse> call, Response<SeriesAwardResponse> response) {
        if (response.body().getData() != null) {
            awardModel.clear();
            awardModel.addAll(response.body().getData().get(0).getAwards());
            awardModelAdapter = new AwardModelAdater(context, awardModel);
            //dialogList_loadingProgress.hide();
            infoSerialFrag_AwardAcademyRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            infoSerialFrag_AwardAcademyRecyclerView.setAdapter(awardModelAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SeriesAwardResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        //dialogList_loadingProgress.hide();
    }
});
```

**Award class :**

```
public class Award {

    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("year")
    @Expose
    private Integer year;
    @SerializedName("celebrity")
    @Expose
    private Celebrity celebrity;
    @SerializedName("won")
    @Expose
    private Boolean won;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Celebrity getCelebrity() {
        return celebrity;
    }

    public void setCelebrity(Celebrity celebrity) {
        this.celebrity = celebrity;
    }

    public Boolean getWon() {
        return won;
    }

    public void setWon(Boolean won) {
        this.won = won;
    }

}
```

Comment: where you are inflating all these data on Layout, then first check condition. if Won is false then put their visibility GONE else Make them visibility VISIBLE

Comment: @nihal_softy, can you send to me code with my above codes? please

Comment: This would cause unnecessary overhead on View creation and then making into invisible!

Comment: @Mani yes you are little bit right but problem is that suppose use want to add different logic when won is false. so I have to add all data in model class.

Comment: @nihal_softy: For that I would provide a another approach having another EMPTY_VIEW_TYPE for that case in which empty view type would be inflated for condition met flag

Comment: Post your layout code and I strongly encourage you to be clear on question and all controls you use on UI!

Comment: Could you post your layout code and update your question on how you filter the data items on recycler view? Ideally you should be having spinner/radio button to allow user to choose on which category they wish to see!

Comment: @Mani, I want show this items automatically no change by user

Comment: At what event  you want to show won/not won data, if not user selection? Or you want to group data based on won & not won?

Comment: @Mani, I want first check items from server, I each item won=true, **just** show this items and not show won=false items. else not have won=true, then show all of won=false items. and show this items automatically not change by user.

Comment: Do you mean, by default show all "won=false" if no "won=true" from server?
If atleast one item with "won=true" found, show only "won=true" items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the RecyclerView logic, rather you should filter the `response.body().getData().get(0).getAwards()` model to have only `"won": true`

Replace below code with `onResponse()` of **My activity code:**

```
if (response.body().getData() != null) {
    awardModel.clear();
    private List<Award> won = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Award> lost = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Award award: response.body().getData().get(0).getAwards()){
        if(!award.won){
            lost.add(award);
        }else {
            won.add(award);
        }
    }
    if(won.size()>0)
    {
        awardModel.addAll(won);
    } else{
        awardModel.addAll(lost);
    }
    awardModelAdapter = new AwardModelAdater(context, awardModel);
    //dialogList_loadingProgress.hide();
    infoSerialFrag_AwardAcademyRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    infoSerialFrag_AwardAcademyRecyclerView.setAdapter(awardModelAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Share me your "Award" class

Comment: when use your code, just show won == true items, if won == false not show items. I want when won == false. show this items

Comment: I want when won == false, show won==false items. if won == true, show won==true items. please help me my friend

Comment: Answer Updated! I strongly encourage you to understand code base rather blindly copy pasting the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Filterable` interface:

```
public class AwardModelAdater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AwardModelAdater.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {...}
```

Inside adapter create 2 lists of data, one original and one filtered:

```
private List<Award> model;
private List<Award> original;
```

And create filter class:

```
private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        String filterString = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        final List<Award> list = original;
        int count = list.size();
        final List<Award> newList = new ArrayList<>(count);
        String filterableWon;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Award a = list.get(i);
            filterableWon = String.valueOf(a.getWon());
            if (filterableWon.equals(filterString)) {
                newList.add(a);
            }
        }

        results.values = newList;
        results.count = newList.size();

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        model = (List<Award>) filterResults.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And create instace of filter inside adapter:

```
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
```

And override getFilter method:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}
```

Then you can use filter like this:
`awardModelAdapter.getFilter().filter(String.valueOf(true))`

Comment: This works great.  Thank you.  When the recyclerView loads, I get a quick blink of the entire recylcerView before the searched view shows.  Anyway to eliminate that?